why are the coefficients different when I design an IIR bandpass filter using butter compared to using the Filter Design Toolbox?
In matlab, for the same parameters, why are the coefficients different when I design an IIR bandpass filter using butter compared to using the Filter Design Toolbox?
When I run a command in matlab
fs=500;
low_cutoff = 1;
high_cutoff = 50;
wn = [low_cutoff, high_cutoff] / (fs / 2);
[b, a] = butter(2, wn, 'bandpass');
result：
b=[0.0652016551604359 0   -0.130403310320872  0   0.0652016551604359]
a=[1 -3.14636562553919    3.71754597063790 -1.99118301927812 0.420045500522989]
However, if I use the toolbox and convert the coefficients to Num, Den，

result:
Num=[0.241267312452136    0   -0.241267312452136]
Den=[1    -1.51128201306721   0.517465375095727]
Why are the two coefficients different?
Why is the amplitude response different?
And why are the lengths of the coefficients of b and a 2n+1 (where n is the filter order)? Usually it looks like n+1.


Because matlab’s butter function doubles the order for bandpass or band stop filters. You can see that your butter-generated filter has order 4

According to the Matlab butter() documentation:

'bandpass' specifies a bandpass filter of order 2n if Wn is a two-element vector.

Therefore, halve your filter order argument to the butter() function. Here is a screenshot showing I get the same result from Matlab's Filter Designer and the butter() function when I do so:

